# « Aviser », « faire savoir », « indiquer », « faire connaître » ,« dire »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Je veux savoir ce que vous diriez à l’oral dans le contexte ci-bas; je cherche une formulation qui se dirait aisément et sans avoir l’air d’une personne qui cherche à faire de l’esprit.

J’ai changé de médicament contre l’anxiété récemment et j’en prends désormais un autre contre les reflux gastriques,
est-ce que je dois vous (médecin spécialiste)

…**aviser** des changements au cas où l’un des nouveaux entrerait en interaction avec celui que vous m’injectez dans l’œil ?

…**faire savoir** les changements au cas où l’un des nouveaux entrerait en interaction avec celui que vous m’injectez dans l’œil ?

…**faire connaître** les changements au cas où l’un des nouveaux entrerait en interaction avec celui que vous m’injectez dans l’œil ?

…**donner** les noms des nouveaux au cas où l’un d’entre eux entrerait en interaction avec celui que vous m’injectez dans l’oeil?

N’hésitez pas à me proposer des refontes complètes de la phrase en question.

---

Version simplifiée:

Je prends de nouveaux médicaments depuis la dernière consultation, est-ce que je dois vous

…dire les nouveaux médicaments.

…dire les changements.

…faire connaître les changements.

… […]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Je prends de nouveaux médicaments depuis ma dernière consultation avec vous. Est-ce que vous souhaitez que je vous donne leurs noms ?

Comment: Merci jlliagre d’aider un illettré en devenir. C’est très apprécié de ta part.

Comment: « Leur nom », « leurs noms » ou « le nom de chacun »

Comment: J’ai trouvé ma réponse.

Comment: https://amp.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/10/26/37003-20171026ARTFIG00006-leurs-ne-faites-plus-la-faute.php

Comment: https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2773

Comment: Ça pourrait faire l’objet d’une autre question…

Comment: Le singulier était probablement valide car chaque médicament n'a qu'un nom mais le pluriel évite de se poser des questions...

Comment: *L’Académie française nous précise que l’usage hésite encore entre le singulier et le pluriel lorsqu’un nom désigne une réalité dont plusieurs possesseurs possèdent chacun un exemplaire.* Le singulier était donc valide en effet.